# Запятая в предложении: «У приезжающих сюда создаётся впечатление(,) словно сама хозяйка встречает гостей»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> У приезжающих сюда создаётся впечатление словно сама хозяйка встречает гостей

Стоит ли ставить запятую перед «словно»?

Comment: можно задать вопрос - создается впечатление...какое...? словно хозяйка...

Answer (score 3):

"*Словно*" не очень подходит здесь по смыслу: если впечатление (по мнению рассказчика) было обманчивым, то лучше "*будто*", если же нужно высказаться нейтрально, то лучше простое "*что*".   В обоих случаях запятая **нужна** - для отделения придаточного предложения:

> У приезжающих сюда создаётся впечатление, будто/что сама хозяйка
>   встречает гостей.

"Словно" больше годится для сопоставления реального с правдоподобным мнимым (а не мнимого с мнимым - впечатления с его же содержанием):

> Хозяйка так приветлива, словно она гостей встречает (а не судебных
>   приставов).

Comment: Например, так: *У входа в дом стоит восковая фигура женщины с хлебом и солью, словно сама хозяйка встречает гостей*.

Comment: Да, хороший пример со "словно".

Answer (score 2):

Запятая ставится:

**У приезжающих сюда создаётся (такое) впечатление (какое?), словно сама хозяйка встречает гостей**.

Это СПП с придаточным определительным,  связь местоименно-союзная, союз СЛОВНО, опорное слово (определяемое существительное) ***впечатление***.